# Next.JS 13 - Manipulating SSR components from CS components

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

While rendering the main content (MC) with NextJS 13, I strongly prefer utilizing Server-Side Rendering (SSR) components due to their recommendation in Google's Quality Guidelines. However, I've come across a use case where the MC is dynamically changed at runtime by a nested Client-Side (CS) component. As far as I can tell, there are two potential solutions to address this problem while still retaining the advantages of SSR. Nevertheless, both approaches come with their drawbacks:

**#1** - Modify the HTML of the SSR component from the nested CS component using JavaScript query selectors. The primary downside of this approach is that CS components must incorporate hardcoded logic, given that SSR components cannot pass callbacks.

**#2** - Trigger a route push event with parameters. The main drawback of this strategy is that it results in a page refresh and fetches content again.

I have a sense that I might not be adhering to best practices due to these associated disadvantages. Could someone explain the most effective solution for manipulating SSR components from nested CS components and provide clarifications or examples?

**Solution #1 example;**

```
// app/page.tsx
export default function Page() {
  const id = "myGeneratedId"
  const items = fetch("/getAll")
  return (
    <>
      <Filter id={id}/>
      <div id={id}>
        {items.map((x) => (
          <span>{x.name}</span>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

```
// components/filter.tsx
"use client"

export function Filter({ id }) {
  const hideNames = () =>
    document
      .getElementById(id)
      ?.querySelectorAll("span")
      .forEach((x) => (x.style.display = "none"))

  return <button onClick={hideNames}>hide names</button>
}
```

**Solution #2 example;**

```
// app/page.tsx
export default function Page({ params }) {
  const id = "myGeneratedId"
  const items = fetch(`/getAll`, { body: params })
  return (
    <>
      <Filter />
      <div>
        {items.map((x) => (
          <span>{x.name}</span>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

```
// components/filter.tsx
"use client"

import Router from "next/router"

export function Filter() {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() =>
        Router.push({
          pathname: "/",
          query: { params: ["name1", "name2"] },
        })
      }
    >
      hide names
    </button>
  )
}
```